# .Split method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing, methods, split

```
const timeHorizonValues = [
  { value: "SHORT", description: "", key: "1" }, 
  { value: "AVERAGE", description: "", key: "2" },
  { value: "LONGEST", description: "", key: "3" },
];

const liquidityNeedValues = [
  {
    value: "VERY_IMPORTANT",
    description: "",
    key: "1",
  },
  {
    value: "SOMEWHAT_IMPORTANT",
    description: "",
    key: "2",
  },
  {
    value: "NOT_IMPORTANT",
    description: "I",
    key: "3",
  },
];

// VALUES OF liquidityNeedValues + timeHorizonValues = COMBINED IN blahBlahBlahValues. NEW VALUE = value: "NOT_IMPORTANT/LONGEST"

const blahBlahBlahValues = 
  {
    value: "NOT_IMPORTANT/LONGEST",
    description:
      "hey there.",
    key: "1",
  },
  {
    value: "NOT_IMPORTANT/LONGEST_1",
    description: "25 years",
    key: "2",
  },
  {
    value: "NOT_IMPORTANT/LONGEST_2",
    description: "80 years",
    key: "3",
  },
  {
    value: "NOT_IMPORTANT/LONGEST_3",
    description: "70 years",
    key: "4",
  },
  {
    value: "NOT_IMPORTANT/AVERAGE",
    description: "200 years",
    key: "5",
  },
  {
    value: "SOMEWHAT_IMPORTANT/SHORT",
    description:
      "Under 5 years",
    key: "6",
  },
];    



let hello = {
      timeHorizon: values.timeHorizon,
      liquidityNeeds: values.liquidityNeeds,
    };
```

> So to give some context, I am currently displaying two questions.`timeHorizonValues`+ `liquidityNeedValues`. I combined these two values/questions and created blahBlahBlahValues. On the frontend I am combining these two values, but the backend still needs to receive them as separate values **how the where initially**.

I need to be pulling the values for both timeHorizon and liquidityNeeds from blahBlahBlahValues **already did this** and then setting those as the values to the timeHorizon and liquidityNeeds in the hello object. I need to use the .split() method for strings as a way to separate the values from the single string. I need some help trying to solve this.  The frontend is merging these two fields but the backend expects them as two individual values! thank you for your help!

Comment: This question needs to be reworked, it doesn't make any sense. `timeHorizon` and `liquidityNeeds` don't exist on `blahBlahBlahValues`.

Comment: The values of timeHorizon + liquidityNeeds are merged/combined in blahBlahBlahValues. I added to the code section.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs to be reworked as what your asking for doesn't line up with your code. I am guessing you are looking for something like this:

```
const newValues = blahBlahBlahValues.map( item => {
   const tempValues = item.value.split("/");
  return {timeHorizon:tempValues [0],liquidityNeeds:tempValues [1]};
}
```

Now you can iterate newValues and submit to your backend.

```
newValues.forEach(item => console.log(item.timeHorizon));
```

Updated:

```
  const newValues = items.map(item => {
    const tempValues = item.value.split("/");
    return {
      timeHorizon: {
        value: tempValues[1],
        description: item.description,
        key: item.key
      },
      liquidityNeeds: {
        value: tempValues[0],
        description: item.description,
        key: item.key
      }
    };
  });  
  newValues.forEach(item => {
    console.log("timeHorizon");
    console.log(item.timeHorizon);
    console.log("liquidityNeeds");
    console.log(item.liquidityNeeds);
  });
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your help! I just rephrased the question.

Comment: updated to give you two seperate objects inside of new values. so you can loop through them in the forEach and access them.